# After clicking a link that loads into an iFrame how can I have the page go back to the top?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, iframe, hyperlink

I have a list of links that are on the left side of my page that extend further down than my iframe on the right side of my page.  how can I have it so that when I click a link and the iframe reloads that the window also resets to the top of the page?

EDIT: I tried doing an anchor but this wouldn't work because the content is in an iframe.

Comment: Is using javascript acceptable?

Comment: yes in fact that's what I ended up doing. Used a function with OnClick() and set the window.location.hash equal to my anchor id and it worked. Thanks for checking on this much appreciated!

Comment: I was going to suggest the `scrollIntoView();` method - although I'm not entirely sure how cross-browser safe it is.  [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

> - **_blank** Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
> - **_self**  Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
> - **_parent**    Opens the linked document in the parent frame
> - **_top**   Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
> - **framename**  Opens the linked document in a named frame

_top will make the job for you

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp